# How to force username and password entry in C# / VS web app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

I am trying to force user to enter username and password when they run my C#/SQL web application.  This was developed in VS 2008 on a 32-bit XP.  The current connection string I'm using in my web.config file is:

```
<add name="AdventureWorksConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=SIDEKICK;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Persist Security Info=false; " 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But it still doesn't prompt for a username and password.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you mean by "enter username and password". I'm going to assume that the browser should pop up a small dialog asking for credentials.

Also, the connection string is missing in your post, so there may be something else I'm missing. Be aware that you can't use "**<**" and "**>**" symbols in posts.

---

### So, here's the answer

In your IIS administration, you have to select "**Basic Authentication**" for your website and remove "**Anonymous Access**". Open IIS Management, right-click your website, select **Properties**, then go to "**Directory Security**" tab, click "**Edit**" in the "**Authentication and Access Control**" section.